# Ajax not getting executed on tab close

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm writing this js function to get executed when the page is being closed. Basically to send the logout time of a person to the server. But for some reason, I get nothing written on the server. My current code looks like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
function closingCode(){
    var logout=getCookie("current-time");
    $.ajax({ url: './scripts/Functions.php',
 data: {function2call: 'sendLogout', arguments: [person_ID,"Logout","Logout",logout]},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                 console.log("Sent Analytics Value (Logout)");
         }
});
return false;
}
```

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/19538231/6309457

Comment: need to add piece of code `e.preventDefault()`, please read (this doc)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload]

Comment: Use the beacon API, this is what it was made for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API